# How to resolve this error in subversion installation?

Tags: svn

I tried following [this tutorial](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/04/setting-up-subversion-on-windows.html) but I get this error:

```
C:\>net start svnserver
System error 2 has occurred.

The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Comment: A file was not found. Most likely the configuration string containing the location of your repositories is wrong. There should be an error log for more information I think (not sure).

Answer (score 1):

Did you perform the preceding step in the tutorial?

```
sc create svnserver binpath= "c:\svn\bin\svnserve.exe --service -r c:\svn\repository" 
displayname= "Subversion" depend= Tcpip start= auto
```

Did it work? Is the path correct?Does the service appear in the list of services in the Windows control panel services app?

Answer (score 1):

The sc command is "tricky".  Note that there cannot be spaces before any of the equals, and there must be a space immediately after each equals.  Additionally, the value for binpath must be in quotation marks (the so-called "double quotes").

Also make certain to double check the correct path for the `svnserve` program.  Depending on what version of Windows you're running, and which Subversion package you downloaded, the executables might be in `Program Files (x86)` instead of `Program Files`.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than `c:\svn\bin\svnserve.exe`, go to where you installed Subversion and look at the address for `svnserve.exe`.

I installed Subversion in my `Program Files (x86)` folder and set up my repository in `c:\svn\repository`.  So  entered the following command and it worked.

```
sc create svnserver binpath= "c:\Program Files (x86)\WANdisco\Subversion\svnserve.exe --service -r c:\svn\repository" displayname= "Subversion" depend= Tcpip start= auto
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you go with Visual SVN.  It is a commercial product based on svn.  However,they have a free version.

The free version installs with a simple click of a button (with an msi package) and creating a repository is as simple.

It is great as it provides a visual interface for doing all things SVN: creating repositories, creating users, enabling integration with AD servers, moving repositories,...

I find that I use the administration functions of SVN so rarely that I always go back and have to find the commands and syntax.  With visual SVN, all you have to do is find the correct command in the menus.